# How do you multiply a character in C like Python?

Tags: c

I come from a Python background and I know that in Python you can do something like this:

```
'g'*8
gggggggg
```

Now, I know you can perform a for loop to get the same result in C, but is there actually a way to multiply strings and characters in C?

Comment: You don't, you use a loop. C is not Python.

Comment: No, there is no built-in operator to do this. I'm not even familiar with a standard function to do so. However, writing your own function to do this is fairly trivial. As you said, it requires a for loop.

Comment: The biggest issue in C is handling the memory allocation for the result.  Does the calling code provide the buffer, or does the called function allocate it and require the calling function to release it?

Comment: Darn..I guess for loop is the way to go. I already wrote a for loop, but I guess there was no easy way around this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None. It's not in the C language.

But you can get them from library which is pretty useful. For your question, you can define an char array and use `memset`([doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/)).

```
char str[9];
memset(str, 'g', 8);
str[8] = '\0';
```

Then the `str` is "gggggggg". `str[8]` should be a terminal `\0` when represents string.

Comment: Ah, I haven't learned about the memset() yet, but now I what it is and how it can be used for this case. Thanks

Comment: I'd write `memset(str, 'g', sizeof str - 1); str[sizeof str - 1] = '\0';` so if you want to change the length you only need to update one line. And if the length is variable, you might want to use `malloc` rather than defining an array object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You cannot multiply strings in c. You have to use other methods.

Since implementing the functionality is simple, i'd like to elaborate what happens when you try to use the same semantics.

There are two things that might happen. In python there is no difference between `"c"` and `'c'`, both are *strings* of length one. In c language, those would semantically be very different.

`'c'*8` is valid c code, because it coverts character into its integer value and performs standard integer multiplication.

c does not have a native string type, and `"c"` would have type of `char*`, and at least my compiler says there is no operator `*` for `char*` and `int`, although I believe some older compilers might allow to convert pointer to an integer and perform operation, however it rarely makes any sense (note that `+`/`-` operators are used and useful).

Moreover, since you cannot define ( or overload ) operators in c, there is no standard-compatible way to achieve it. It would be possible to implement such semantics valid in c++ but not c.

Comment: You won't get an error for multiplying a character by an integer, because characters are integral types. Maybe you mean multiplying a character string by an integer, since a string is an array.

Comment: When I tried to multiply it, nothing happened, but it did compile correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a useful answer. I don't think he really cares whether he can actually use the `*` operator to do this, he just wanted to know if there's something analogous. He's just using that as an example of the corresponding Python syntax.

Comment: @Barmar I am not saying it's useful. I don't think OP uses python syntax as analog. I believe they ask for a similar syntax. And to this answer is simple. Not possible. I chose to explain why and what happens if you try similar syntax in c. I don't count on +1s on this. I still think it's somewhat informative. You can downvote if you think it's useless yapping =).

Comment: The accepted answer shows that your "Not possible" is not true. It's not a single expression like in Python, but it's still very simple.

Comment: Of course it is not possible. Please not, that in c at no point, you have the notion of multiplying a character. It's obvious you can have the same functionality but it's impossible to have the same semantics. This what I understood by the "like Python" part. In c++ you could have the same semantics too. I probably failed to underline the focal point, of my thought. I'll try to improve it.